# Talks- what does it mean here?

Tags: word-meaning

Have him know I miss his **talks**.

What does **talks** mean here?

Comment: That is in the dictionary. Under: talk, noun.

Comment: We need a little more context.  It could be that the speeches he gives in front of an audience are missed, or it could be his phone conversions, or something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When they say *talks* they mean *conversations*. As in:

> Have him know that I miss our conversations.

either that or possibly in context they mean

> Have him know that I miss his speeches.